# Setting up static assets paths, routing endpoints with koa and various middleares

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

### **Question:**

1. How can I set up my static files so that both directories are visible to my `index.html`.
2. How can I send my `index.html` when you hit the default route using koa-router vs. just a `.json` file when I make an AJAX Get request?

**Requirements:**

*I need static directories to be visible in my apps `src/index.html`*

- `node_modules` needs to be open for js libs.
- `src/assets` needs to be open for images.

*I need a router for 2 purposes :*

- 1) serving up the initial `index.html`
- 2) CRUD endpoints to my DB.

Notes: I'm totally willing to add/subtract any middleware.  But I would rather not change how I organize my directories.

**Directory Structure:**

[image: directory structure]

**Middleware:**

- [koa-static](https://github.com/koajs/static)  // cant serve node_modules + src directory.
- [koa-send](https://github.com/koajs/send)  // can send static files but then breaks koa-static
- [koa-router](https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router) // cannot

**`app.js`**

```
var serve = require('koa-static');
var send = require('koa-send');
var router = require('koa-router')();
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();


// need this for client side packages.
app.use(serve('./node_modules/'));

// need this for client side images, video, audio etc.
app.use(serve('./src/assets/'));

// Will serve up the inital html until html5 routing takes over.
router.get('/', function *(next) {
    // send up src/index.html
});

// will serve json open a socket
router.get('/people', function *(next) {
  // send the people.json file
});

app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());

// errors
app.on('error', function(err, ctx){
  log.error('server error', err, ctx);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Morningharwood</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>suchwow</h1>
  <img src="./assets/image1.png" alt="butts"> <!-- will 404 with routing -->

  <script src="./node_modules/gun/gun.js"></script> <!-- will always 404 -->
  <script>
    var gun = Gun(options);
    console.log(gun);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry. can you explain in detail the need for serving node_modules?

Comment: I install all my front end packages via npm.  I can move them or isolate the serving of those files more if you have any suggestions.  But I really like using npm for all my package management

Comment: Agreed , but that doesn't mean that you should "serve it" through your server. you should use an external tool ( even should be posible to use npm) to copy the needed ones to a 'viewable' place on your 'build' task

Comment: Great idea! I can totally write that task!  Assuming that's true could you help me solve the problem too?

Comment: check the answer in 5 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. it happens that I'm developing a similar kind of app

There's no problem on using koa-static to serve you static content and koa-router for you api endpoint. I never used koa-send directly. but I think you doesn't need too, given your set up

The only thing that matters is the order when attaching middleware to koa app. Try to attach koa-static first for your assets ( and maybe even index.html) and later use the koa-router for your api. Requests trying to get some static file never reach the router. and this way the router only responsibility will be serving your api

If that's not posible ( for example, because you have a bunch of non-static html files to server, consider taht you can have more than one router per app, even nesting one inside the other

( If the answer is not enough, give some time to cook a simple example. I'll post it as soon as possible)

EDIT: added a quick and dirty example [here](https://gist.github.com/develmts/a3c1f89c8327f33f143da230ad52c7ae). Probably it doesn't work out of the box, but it's enough to get the idea

Comment: Will try again tonight.  Just stepped out thanks for the help

Comment: .@matthew-harwood check the example and tell me if you got the idea

Comment: This worked the only problem is some typos and inside the route you must called `yield`